# Storybook with React Context, decorator causing story not to show up in Storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm trying out Storybook with React, and I have a component (`Header`) which is wrapped by `AuthContext`. Following the docs, I've added this context provider as a decorator, but that causes the story to disappear from the storybook story list. When I comment out the decorator code, the story reappears, but then I get an error since the Header needs that context and doesn't have it.

Here's the code:

```
import { ComponentStory, ComponentMeta } from '@storybook/react';
import Header from '../components/header/Header';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthContext } from '../utils/contexts/authContext';
import { fakeAuthData } from '../utils/testUtils';

export default {
  title: 'Header',
  component: Header,
  parameters: {
    layout: 'fullscreen',
  },
} as ComponentMeta<typeof Header>;

const Template: ComponentStory<typeof Header> = (args) => (
  <Router>
    <Header {...args} />
  </Router>
);

export const Beep = Template.bind({});
Beep.args = {
  isWorkspaceSidebarOpen: true,
  currentTenant: { id: '0Ym0tVEZKUGprzr2fsHfw', name: 'Test - User 1' },
};
Beep.decorators = [
  (Story) => (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={fakeAuthData()}>
      <Story />
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  ),
];`
```

Comment: Does `Story` need to be typed? `import { Story } from '@storybook/react';`, `(Story: Story) => (....)`?

Comment: Thanks for the help @DrewReese, but the answer was because of my fake data.. First time using Storybook! lolz

Comment: No worries. I knew I should have stuck to my gut feeling and asked what `fakeAuthData` did. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the answer. My issue was `fakeAuthData()` containing `jest.fn()` (I grabbed this from my jest tests), which obviously won't work outside of jest.